# SQL equivalent to CouchDB for 2 way replication

Tags: replication, merge-replication, couchdb

Are there any SQL server variants (i.e MySQL, Postgresql etc) that handle replication as well as couch db does and offers client side replication (2 way)?

I'm in the early stages of my app which is currently using PouchDB / CouchDB as a key point about the app is being able to go offline then replicate when back online. I know the servers themselves can replicate but I'm basically looking to have an offline version of the database available to the client as well (which is what PouchDB / CouchDB achieves).

Answer (score 4):

The way CouchDB's replication mechanism is created and integrated is kind of unique. This has to do with the historical situation, that CouchDB should be able to live in a distributed world from the beginning. That said, "older" databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL do not have these features, because there was never a need for it.

It is very important to understand, that MySQL and PostgreSQL do offer replication but not in the way CouchDB does. There is [MySQL Percona](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster) and [PostgreSQL BRD](https://2ndquadrant.com/en-us/resources/bdr/) but one has to go through a more time consuming setup process in comparison to CouchDB where you simply add a replication document with the source and target in the _replicator database.

So as far as I know, it will be difficult to find something comparable to the mechanisms and features you are looking for.

Comment: That's the conclusion I seem to be coming to as well. It seems I want the best of both worlds and it doesn't (yet) exist. It's forced me to go down the Couch route (as offline is more important in my app than making my life easier querying the DB and dealing with relational data). I'll see if any other comments come in over the next couple of days otherwise mark this as the answer.

Comment: @webnoob Have you got any other solution to this?

Comment: Afraid not, I stuck with couchdb.